# How to iterate a list up to certain element/index in terraform?

Tags: terraform

This is simple in other language by using **for** or **do while** statement. Being a novice, I still can't figure out to do it in Terraform.

The real case that I need to do is to build a connection string to mongoDB replica-set service. The replication_factor is 3, 5 or 7 which means I need to create a list of 2, 4, or 6 hostnames/addresses.

I come up with the following code sofar:

```
locals {
  uri_list = [
    "@${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}1.mongodb.${var.region}.rds.aliyuncs.com:${var.db_port}",
    "@${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}2.mongodb.${var.region}.rds.aliyuncs.com:${var.db_port}",
    "@${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}3.mongodb.${var.region}.rds.aliyuncs.com:${var.db_port}",
    "@${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}4.mongodb.${var.region}.rds.aliyuncs.com:${var.db_port}",
    "@${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}5.mongodb.${var.region}.rds.aliyuncs.com:${var.db_port}",
    "@${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}6.mongodb.${var.region}.rds.aliyuncs.com:${var.db_port}"
  ]

  uri_list_out = [
    for uriname in local.uri_list :
      lower(uriname)
      if substr(uriname,length("${alicloud_mongodb_instance.tyk_mongodb-test.id}") + 1, 1) < var.mongos_config["${var.environment}"]["replication_factor"]
  ]
}
```

What I expect from

```
output "uri_list_out" {
  value = local.uri_list_out
}
```

is the first two elements of `uri_list` but instead I got only **[1,2]** for replication_factor = 3. Seems like **if** instruction in **for** also modify the output ???

I appreciate any hints to solve this problem.

Hendro

Comment: For expressions in Terraform are not like imperative languages loops; they are something akin to list comprehension. I’m not really sure what you’re trying to do here, maybe you can post the result you want and we can work from there?

Comment: I need to build this connection string -->  mongodb://userid:password@**dds-d9jec3993b7a6d241.mongodb.ap-southeast-5.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717,dds-d9jec3993b7a6d242.mongodb.ap-southeast-5.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717**/admin?replicaSet=mgset-1100377678. The problem is with the hostnames that starts with dds and end with 3717. The number of hostnames listed are variable, could be 2, 4 or 6 depend on the replication factor.

Comment: the above example is for replication factor 3 hence 2 hostnames... the code should be able to handle this variable replication factor..

Comment: Well now I realize that instead of iterating the list using loop, I should just use lookup  element().... ;-) this is especially true for terraform....

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you really need is the `slice(list, startindex, endindex)` function:

```
uri_list_out = [
  for uri in slice(local.uri_list, 0, var.mongos_config[var.environment]["replication_factor"] - 1) :
  replace(uri, "/^@/", "") # Remove the leading '@'
]
```

---

> [The docs for the slice function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/slice.html)
>
> ```
> > slice(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 1, 3)
> [
>   "b",
>   "c",
> ]
> ```

Comment: Iso thanks... that's the loop solution that I'm looking for...